# odoo - explanation @api.multi - recordset

Tags: odoo, recordset, odoo-11

In odoo v11 when i use @api.multi decorator, the self variable is the actual recordset. But what records are  in that recordset?

For example:
In odoo I click on a partner. The partner has a computed field. The method of that computed field is decorated with @api.multi. In that recordset on the 0th place, there is the record i want. But why there are other records?

I know what @api.one does - iterating through the recordset and redefining the self variable as the current recordset.

I'm facing this problem, because i want to fill fields via a WebService call from Navision at the time I click on a partner. So i defined a temp field which is computed by a method. in that method i call the webservice and update the four fields i want to show.

any explanations / suggestions?

Thanks.
-JS

Comment: In compute methods you get the list of records that needs to recompute the value because something changes that trigger computting for all of them..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I interpret your question 100% correctly.

api.one() is deprecated since V9 due to common misinterpretation by developers, according to [ORM API V11 documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html)
Successor of api.one() is by using api.multi(), within the method, call ensure_one when needed.

If your model expects only **One** record in the particular recordsets, do this

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('your_temp_field')
def _my_method(self):
    self.ensure_one() # self is a recordsets, if it contains more than 1 record, error will be raised.
    for record in self:
        record.field1 = 'value1'
        record.field2 = 'value2'
        record.field3 = 'value3'
        record.field4 = 'value4'
```

If your model expects more than **One** record, but you need to modify specific record(s).
You can simply use some if-else statements for targeted records.
If you only want the 0th position, use **index field** as your condition instead.

Be aware index adds overhead to your database in terms of performance and size as well since default search/sorting function are based on that.

You can find a good example [here](https://odooforbeginnersblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/difference-between-api-one-and-api-multi/#more-361).